# Change number of items bought in Prestashop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I have made a custom shopping cart in prestashop, I now need to increase the number of items bought in my shop manually. I guess this can be done by modifying the database.  I tried changing the ps_product_sale table, but to no use. Can anyone suggest as to how to do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by making changes in the ps_order_detail table. In that table, PS stores all information for an ordered product like product id, name, product purchased quantities etc etc.

There is a column named **product_quantity**, change it and it will change the number of products bought.

Comment: How to add a new row ? There are so many columns. Is it necessary to add details of each column. I don't know the value of many column, So what should I fill it with ?

Comment: if you are doing it manually, then you have to do it manually, else write a script or query for it. Also i think you can modify product details for an order at admin also in the Orders section.